# Publishing to an topic on AWS iot from lambda function [Java]

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I'm trying to publish on a topic on my AWS Iot from my lambda function which is triggered by an alexa skill. Which class of `AWSClient` is the right one to do so?

Based on an answer on stackoverflow i know that i need to use the `HTTP` method to publish from an aws lambda function to aws iot, rather than `MQTT`. As the class `AWSIotDataClient` is deprecated, I don't know which class to use. It is suggested by AWS to use `AwsIotClientBuilder`, which I did but what now?

```
    AWSIotClientBuilder client =  AWSIotClientBuilder.standard();
    client.setEndpointConfiguration(conf);
    client.setCredentials(new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
        @Override
        public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
            return cred;
        }

        @Override
        public void refresh() {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AWSIotDataClient` is not deprecated, just the constructors are deprecated, as are the constructors of all `AWSClient` implementations in favor of builders. You should use `AwsClientBuilder.build()` to obtain an instance of `AWSIotDataClient`. Then you can call the `publish()` method on the `AWSIotDataClient` instance to publish to your IoT topic.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If I want an AWSIotDataClient to publish to IoT I need the AWSIotDataClientBuiler, right? My problem is when I want to build() the AWSIotDataClientBuilder I get the error that this method returns an AWSIotData; which is an Interface which is implemented by AWSIotDataClient, do I need to cast it? And additional question: Do I place this client stuff in every IntentHandler class individually or in the StreamHanler class?

Comment: For your first question, there's no need to cast `AWSIoTData` since it has a `publish()` method, just use the interface.

Comment: Thank you for your help. May I ask if you have some kind of example code. I've been searching for days now and haven't found anything that helps. I also have the issue that as soon as I add the maven dependency for aws-core or aws-iot and upload the jar then to lambda i get an endpoint error. That happens even if I don't touch the code at all the dependencies are enough to crash everything

Answer (score 0):

```
AWSIotData awsIotDataClient = AWSIotDataClientBuilder.defaultClient(); // add your AWS creds to environment vars to test locally

    awsIotDataClient.publish(new PublishRequest()
                                     .withPayload(ByteBuffer.wrap(("{\"some\":\"message\"}").getBytes()))
                                     .withQos(1)
                                     .withTopic("your/topic"));
```